# Executing c++ object file in command line gives different output than VScode debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, memory, g++

I was following a youtube tutorial that made a simple memory allocation tracker by overriding the `new` and `delete` operators. It uses an object to keep track of the stats. Its pretty simple, here is the code

```
#include <iostream>

struct AllocationMetics
{
    uint32_t TotalAllocated = 0;
    uint32_t TotalFreed = 0;
    uint32_t TotalUsage() { return TotalAllocated - TotalFreed; }
};

static AllocationMetics s_AllocationMetrics;

void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    s_AllocationMetrics.TotalAllocated += size;
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void* memory, size_t size) noexcept
{
    s_AllocationMetrics.TotalFreed += size;
    std::cout << size << " added to total freed \n";
    free(memory);
}

void LogMemStat()
{
    std::cout << "Total memory allocated: " << s_AllocationMetrics.TotalAllocated << std::endl
        << "Total memory freed: " << s_AllocationMetrics.TotalFreed << std::endl
        << "Total memory usage: " << s_AllocationMetrics.TotalUsage() << std::endl << std::endl;
}

struct Object
{
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    LogMemStat();

    Object* obj = new Object;
    LogMemStat();

    delete obj;
    LogMemStat();

    return 0;
}
```

when I compile with g++20 on my Mac (running on M1, Monterey 12.2.1) via the command line and execute the object file, the output is

```
Total memory allocated: 0
Total memory freed: 0
Total memory usage: 0

Total memory allocated: 4
Total memory freed: 0
Total memory usage: 4

Total memory allocated: 4
Total memory freed: 0
Total memory usage: 4
```

indicating a memory leak. Now, in VScode, I put a breakpoint in the overriden delete operator to see if it visited the function. Sure enough, in VScode, using g++20 as well, It *did* visit the function. The output in the VScode terminal was this:

```
Total memory allocated: 0
Total memory freed: 0
Total memory usage: 0

Total memory allocated: 4
Total memory freed: 0
Total memory usage: 4

4 added to total freed 
Total memory allocated: 4
Total memory freed: 4
Total memory usage: 0
```

I've run into stuff like this before, but never this blatant. Could someone please shed light on what may be going on here?

Comment: Works for me: Windows 10 + g++ (Rev8, Built by MSYS2 project) 11.2.0. No memory leaks are reported

Comment: There are different versions of `operator delete` - with alignment, without size etc. Maybe try to hook them as well.